# MS-Access hidding and showing a button conditionally through vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, conditional-statements

I am developing a quality control system for my company, and I i want to connect it to a label printer, which is already taken care off, the problem now is with the button itself.

I want the print label button to only be enabled and visible after the whole check was made, what i've got now is this:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

Button_label.Visible = False
Button_label.Enabled = False

End Sub

Private Sub Motor_OK_Change()

Dim ok As Boolean
ok = Motor_OK.Value


If ok = 1 Then
Button_label.Visible = True
Button_label.Enabled = True

End If


End Sub
```

It does work on conceiling the button, but it fails when trying to enable it again and making it visible upon making the check. It's important to refer that I have tried using `If ok = True` instead of `If ok= 1`, I dont know how important that is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing for both conditions (ok=0), perhaps the following will work:

Replace:

```
If ok = 1 Then
    Button_label.Visible = True
    Button_label.Enabled = True
End If
```

With:

```
Button_label.Visible = ok   
Button_label.Enabled = ok
```

**New Solution:**

Instead of using the Form Before_Update event, use Form_Current event. If there is only  1 record, you can also use the Form_Load event. I would also suggest that you remove the Visible property and use only the Enabled one so users can see their is print functionality.

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
  'button_Label.Visible = False
  button_Label.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

Instead of using the Motor_OK Before_Updateevent, use After_Update event

```
Private Sub Motor_OK_AfterUpdate()
    Dim ok As Boolean ' defaults to False

    If IsNumeric(Motor_OK.Value) Then ok = True  ' remove this statement if Motor_OM is
                                                 ' alpha numeric.     

    If Not IsNull(Motor_OK.Value) Then ok = True ' otherwise following statement 
                                                 ' to avoid NULL error

    'button_Label.Visible = ok
    button_Label.Enabled = ok

End Sub
```

Let me know if I can  be of further help.

Comment: lol good thinking, i was complicating, thanks, i will try and get back in a minute ;)

Comment: It doesnt seem to work, am i using the right sub? i tried under Private Sub Motor_OK_AfterUpdate()

Comment: Is Button_Label a Label for a button or the button itself?

Comment: The button itself, sorry about the confusion, i just named it like that because i will be using it to connect to the label printer

Comment: A Button control does not have a before_update event? Can you explain what you mean by "the whole check is made." Do you call another sub for edits?

Comment: yeah, you're right, there's the Motor_OK which is where i get the value for the check being made, the check is a checklist the employee must fill for the quality control

Comment: `What type of control is Mototor_ok?

Comment: It's a regular text control based on a calculated field